# Why isn't there a shorthand property for width and height in CSS?

Tags: css, height, width, shorthand

Wouldn't it be faster to use a shorter property for an item's width and height when coding in CSS?
As of now I have to type:

```
selector {width: 100px; height: 250px;}
```

Which is fast as it is, but I reckon that this would be faster:

```
selector {dimension: 100px 250px;}
```

Is there already a CSS pre-processor that can achieve this? Seems like it would save a bit of time when doing lots of width's and height's.

---

A good example could be the [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) properties:

```
grid-template-columns: 100px 100px;
grid-template-rows: 100px 100px;
```

Would be the same as:

```
grid-template: 100px 100px / 100px 100px;
```

Comment: By faster, I mean faster when typing. Using "dimension: 100px 250px;" is in this case 5 characters shorter than "width: 100px; height: 250px;". And it can be written in one property compared to two (dimension vs width + height).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: *The CSSWG couldn't agree on a name for the shorthand property yet.*

---

The idea isn't new and a lot of people suggested it every now and then over the years. However, there's a current proposal [[css-sizing] Adding a 'size' shorthand for 'width'/'height'](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/820) from the [CSSWG](https://drafts.csswg.org) (*CSS Working Group*).

A lot of things have been discussed already, but a few are still unresolved. Here are some examples:

**What is the proper name?**

Some of the names that where suggested:

- `size`: clashes with the `@page`'s `size`-property
- `dimensions`: probably too long or difficult to spell
- `box-size`: probably too close to `box-sizing`

**How will it work?**

Should it be:

```
<box-size>: <width> <height>?
```

… or closer related to other properties like `padding` or `margin`:

```
<box-size>: <height> <width>?
```

Also: Should it support an additional parameter that will keep the aspect ratio?

**Who's going to support it?**

- Which vendors will support the proposal and the syntax itself?
- Will it enhance the author's experience, so that people will actually use it?

---

As you can see, there might be a shorthand notation in the future, as the CSSWG said recently in their [Minutes Telecon on 2017-08-16](https://www.w3.org/blog/CSS/2017/08/17/minutes-telecon-334/):

> The group agreed that a shorthand for ‘width’/’height’ would be good, but shouldn’t be called ‘size’. However, there wasn’t time to come up with a different name.

---

That being said, of course you can use a CSS pre-processor, to make your life easier. For example, I have a mixin in LESS, that looks like this:

```
.size(@a: null, @b: null) {
    & when not (null = @a) {
        width: @a;
    }

    & when (null = @b) {
        height: @a;
    }

    & when not (null = @b) {
        height: @b;
    }
}
```

Which is as simple as this:

```
.size(100%, 50%);

width: 100%;
height: 50%;
```

… and it supports square elements as well:

```
.size(100%);

width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```

Comment: The answer is outdated now: CSSWG approved a new size property. https://tanalin.com/en/blog/posts/css-size-width-height/

Answer (score 0):

Is a good idea but at this moment official specifications do not allow it.

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion(just an opinion/PoV) would be:
Replace `size` as a shorthand for the `height` and `width` of a selected element.

Example:

```css
size: <height> <width>;
size: 420px 297px;
size: 100% 50%;
size: 15rem 5em;
```

Now about the previous property of `size` used with `@page` should be changed to `page-size`.

Example:

Source: [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page/size)

```css
/* Keyword values for scalable size */
page-size: auto;
page-size: portrait;
page-size: landscape;

/* <length> values */
/* 1 value: height = width */
page-size: 6in;

/* 2 values: width then height */
page-size: 4in 6in;

/* Keyword values for absolute size */
page-size: A4;
page-size: B5;
page-size: JIS-B4;
page-size: letter;

/* Mixing size and orientation */
page-size: A4 portrait;
```